# Editing font-weight of styled html text in JTextPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, bold

I am creating a simple text editor in a `JtextPane` that outputs the text as HTML. The styling options include bold, color and alignment. When I open the editor enter text, everything works fine. But when I save the text in html to a file then read the file and put it back into the editor, I run into a problem. If I save a file that has bold text in it (so the text has `<b>` tags around it) then open it back up and put it into the editor (via `setText`), I am not able to "unbold" the text. The way I am handling bolding/unbolding text via `setCharacterAttributes`. The corresponding code looks like this:

```
MutableAttributeSet attrs = pane.getInputAttributes();
StyleConstants.setBold(attrs, bold);
pane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(p.getSelectionStart(),length,attrs,false);
```

When I print out the HTML after unbolding text in this situation, I see that the  tags are not removed. Although, the editor itself does reflect the change, meaning the text appears as not bold, but the html is unchanged so when it is saved and reloaded in, it is still bold. So I'm not sure why I have this problem after loading html in, but not having the problem when I am editing text from scratch. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you creating an HTMLDocument using `new HTMLDocument()` or `HTMLEditorkit.createDefaultDocument()`?  I've found the latter gives more reliable behavior.

Comment: I have played around with different ways of doing that. Should I be creating an HTMLDocument when I set up the editor? When should I be using it in the editor?

Comment: When the JTextPane is created, it has a default Document that's probably sufficient.  When loading HTML from an external source, you probably want a new Document.  I would try something like `EditorKit editorKit = textPane.getEditorKit(); Document doc = editorKit.createDefaultDocument(); editorKit.read(bufferedReader, doc, 0); textPane.setDocument(doc);`.  If you use read(InputStream…) instead of read(Reader…), remember to catch ChangedCharSetException and re-read the HTML using the discovered charset.

Comment: I tried implemented what you suggested, but still had the same result where when loading in a text with bold I am unable to un-bold it.

Comment: I tried changing the way I set the text to bold by using StyledEditorKit.BoldAction. But I still have the same result.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.  But what does work for me is loading the page using either of the `setPage` methods which JTextPane inherits from JEditorPane.  If I do that, I'm able to change the bold attribute of characters using StyledEditorKit.BoldAction.